# duplicate columns header in data frame in R

Tags: r

I have 4 duplicate column names in my dataframe. When I read the file, R automatically appends .1 or .2 to my duplicate columns
Original table -

```
Date       Temp Press Probability Press Probability
11/4/2015   100   45      0.65      55     0.85
```

What R is currently doing -

```
Date       Temp  Press   Probability  Press.1  Probability.1
11/4/2015   100   45      0.65           55     0.85
```

I don't want R to add .1 to my duplicate columns. Is there a way I can avoid that and keep my parameter name as-is?
Please advise
Thanks

Comment: You can use `check.names = FALSE`, but it is bad practise to use duplicate column names.

Comment: How do you want distinguish between the 'same-name-columns'?

Comment: Hi @jogo, I have address name that I attach to the parameter name after reading the csv file..hence that is being taken care of later in the script

Answer (score 4):

When calling `data.frame()`, you can specify the parameter `check.names = FALSE`. Like in :

```
data.frame(foo = 1:3, foo = 2:4, check.names = FALSE)
```

However, it is often better to avoid duplicates in column names.

Comment: Hi @jlesuffleur, I have address name that I attach to the parameter name after reading the csv file.. Hence the issue with duplicate column names is being taken care of later in the script